# Silverlight 4 WCF The server did not provide a meaningful reply

Tags: wcf, silverlight-4.0, internal-server-error

I'm getting the notorious, "The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error" in my project. It's a WCF PollingDuplex Service, consumed by a Silverlight 4 project.

I'm requesting a document with the service, so I can display it in a viewer in my SL application.

Here is the Server Web Config XML:

```
    <system.serviceModel>

    <extensions>
      <bindingExtensions>
        <add name="pollingDuplex" type="System.ServiceModel.Configuration.PollingDuplexHttpBindingCollectionElement,System.ServiceModel.PollingDuplex, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </bindingExtensions>
    </extensions>


  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

 <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="PortalOnlineBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

 <bindings>
 <pollingDuplex>
        <binding name="SLPollingDuplex" duplexMode="MultipleMessagesPerPoll" />
      </pollingDuplex>
    </bindings>

    <services>
      <service name="Online.Web.PortalOnline" behaviorConfiguration="PortalOnlineBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="pollingDuplex" bindingConfiguration="SLPollingDuplex"
          contract="Notification.IPortalOnline" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://portalonline.com/PortalOnline/IPortalOnline" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>

  </system.serviceModel>
```

Here is the Object I'm trying to return to SL via this WCF service

```
Imports System.ServiceModel
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization
Imports DocCave.Common
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.IO

    <DataContract(NAMESPACE:=DataStore.NAMESPACE)>
    Public Class PortalDocument

        <DataMember()>
        Public Property DataSource As Byte()

        <DataMember()>
        Public Property FileName As String

        <DataMember()>
        Public Property FileType As String

    End Class
```

Here's the WCF Method that is being called:

```
 Public Function GetDocument(sessionUserMeta As Common.UserMetaData, docId As System.Guid) As Notification.PortalDocument Implements Notification.IPortalOnline.GetDocument

        Dim doc As Documents.Document = Documents.Document.GetDocument(docId, sessionUserMeta)

        Dim portalDoc As New PortalDocument

        portalDoc.DataSource = doc.DataSource

        portalDoc.FileName = doc.QueryPackage.DocumentName
        portalDoc.FileType = doc.QueryPackage.Type

        Return portalDoc

    End Function
```

Further Details:

This works perfectly for one or two document request, and the gives me the above mentioned error. For instance, I can load a default document when the SL application is loaded using this method with this service, and it populates perfectly. I can then go to a tree view I have, and select a document, and it works perfect for the first document... but after that, error. Also, I've noticed sometimes it will only work once, if I select certain pdfs that are a bit larger (250kb or so..) ... oh, and I forgot... here's the code in my SL application that is connecting to the WCF service. I'm using the "GetBaseWebAddress()" because I'm using dynamic sub domains, so part of the address can be different each time...

```
Private Sub LoadClient()


        Dim bind As New PollingDuplexHttpBinding(PollingDuplexMode.MultipleMessagesPerPoll)

        Dim endpoint As New EndpointAddress(GetBaseWebAddress() & "PortalOnline/PortalOnline.svc")

        Me.client = New PortalOnline.PortalOnlineClient(bind, endpoint)

        AddHandlers()

    End Sub
```

I've struggled with this for a while, so any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: In order to get streams of files, I ended up reverting to an old school asmx web service for this particular call, and the rest of the web service calls worked. I remember grabbing that proxy class that was created after I finished making any "breaking" changes to the service, and just making it a regular class outside of the resources, and then partial class'ing' tools around the proxy. I then removed the service reference from the project, and just used the proxy classes I created, and all worked well.